# Anyway to prevent ASP.NET regularexpressionvalidation from showing up in client side JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to avoid having ASP.NET's regularexpressionvalidation from using JavaScript to render the regular expression used as a client side validation.  The reason to avoid this sort of thing is to prevent a user from guessing the form's algorithm to determine if the data is valid.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="vldEmail" runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="This email is missing the @ symbol."
     ValidationExpression=".+@.+" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</asp:Content>
```

JavaScript shows the regular expression algorithm.

```
//<![CDATA[
    var ContentPlaceHolder1_vldEmail = document.all ? document.all["ContentPlaceHolder1_vldEmail"] : document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_vldEmail");
    ContentPlaceHolder1_vldEmail.controltovalidate = "ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail";
    ContentPlaceHolder1_vldEmail.errormessage = "This email is missing the @ symbol.";
    ContentPlaceHolder1_vldEmail.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
    ContentPlaceHolder1_vldEmail.validationexpression = ".+@.+";
    //]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set EnableClientScript to false.  This will prevent the scripts from rendering on the client.